# UITableViewCell color doesen't remain the same after i set it in his class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, cell

In my `UITableViewCell` class, i have a function who configures the cellViewColor. I have an array of objects and based on some fields i determinate if the cellView should be gray, red or turquoise. When the table view reuses the cell, it changes the colors in random ways.

```
class WidgetCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var cellView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var mainValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var placeDetails: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var place: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!


func configureCell(entity: EntityModel) {
    self.mainValue.text = entity.monitor?.value
    self.placeDetails.text = entity.name
    self.place.text = entity.name
    self.cellView.applyGradient(withColours: setDeviceStateColor(deviceState: helper(entity: entity) ))
}

private func setDeviceStateColor(deviceState: DeviceState) -> [UIColor] {
    switch deviceState {
    case .alert:
        return [UIColor.red, UIColor.red]
    case .on:
        return [Colors.lightTurcoazLIH, Colors.mediumTurcoazLIH]
    case .off:
        return [UIColor.lightGray,UIColor.darkGray]
    }
}


extension UICollectionViewCell {
func helper(entity: EntityModel) -> DeviceState {
    let state = entity.monitor?.state ?? false
    let alert = entity.monitor?.alert ?? false
    if state && alert {
        return .alert
    } else if state && alert == false {
        return .on
    } else {
        return .off
    }
}
```

Is something related to the deque of the cells.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! WidgetCell
    cell.configureCell(entity: favoriteDevices[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

I hope it's all clear and my explanations are making sense.

Also, here it is the applyGradient(withColors:)

```
func applyGradient(withColours colours: [UIColor]) {
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.cornerRadius = 3
    gradient.colors = colours.map { $0.cgColor }
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```

Comment: can you provide code for `applyGradient(withColours:)` method?

Comment: Only colors are mixed up? Are the `mainValue`, `placeDetail` and `place` correct? If yes, it could be `applyGradient` that does not work properly when set several times.

Comment: I've updated the code. Just the colors are mixed, at every reuse of the cell, the color isn't the same. It almost feels random.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a `default` value in `switch` statement in `setDeviceStateColor` method.

It may helps you. Thank you.